# Docker service exposed port connection times out

Tags: django, docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I have an image that exposes a django app on port 8000
In case A , i create a one node swarm, then deploy a service to the swarm using

```
docker service create --name django -p 8000:8000 --hostname django myrepo/myimage:mytag
```

Then i try to use

```
curl localhost:8000
```

to inspect the service, but the connection seems to hang

Creating a simple container from the same image with

```
 docker run -p 8000:8000 -d myrepo/myimage:mytag
```

will return a response from the previous curl command

Any idea what the issue is?

Thanks